# Authentication error for Outlook using redmail python package

Tags: python, email, outlook, smtp, smtplib

I am trying to send emails using Python, in Outlook. I'm using the redmail package because, as far as I read, it's easier to embed images into the text of the email with it.

When I run the following Python code, I get the error:

```
from redmail import outlook
outlook.username = 'outlook_username@example.com'
outlook.password = 'pass'

outlook.send(
    subject="Example email",
    receivers=['outlook_username@example.com'],
    text="Hi, this is an email."
)
```

> smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled. [FR4P281CA0244.DEUP281.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2023-11-24T08:37:49.541Z 08DBEBAC311EBB8E]')

Does anyone know what I can do?